# How can I make the Windows 10 onscreen keyboard stay visible?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, accessibility, on-screen-keyboard

I can open the on-screen keyboard using the shortcut in the bottom right of my desktop, but as soon as I type any character using my normal, physical keyboard, the on-screen keyboard minimizes.

I would like it to stay visible, to help me practice touch-typing, and to allow me to use the physical and digital keyboard simultaneously. Can I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the on-screen keyboard by clicking the Windows key and search for "On-screen Keyboard". The on-screen keyboard might look slightly different han the one you used earlier.

If this work than you were using the on-screen keyboard for tablet mode in Windows 10 and this on-screen keyboard is minimized by default when using the plugged in physical keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can use onscreen keyboard and physical keyboard at the same time. It will not affect the onscreen keyboard to minimize.

What if you install the latest driver of your keyboard? Or change a new keyboard,seeing if it works well?

Comment: This is on a school lab network, so I'll have to ask the admins there. Thanks for letting me know this isn't a universal behavior.